# IE appendChild from array not working

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, appendchild, clonenode

I have an history feature for a particular,div on my website. Everything worked fine up to now, I was inserting HTML as strings from javascript and re-display them with .innerHTML. Now I try to clean up the javascript from all HTML strings and I have this problem: history browsing of the div works in FF, Chrome and some other, but not IE (8 to 11), can't understand why. Is it a cloneNode() or a reference issue I don't see ?

Below is a small script to reproduce the behaviour, you can play with here: http://jsfiddle.net/yvecai/7e8tksm3/

My code works as follow: each time I display something in Mydiv, I clone it and append it in an array.

The function prev() or next() append the corresponding nodes from the array for display.

The script first create 5 contents '1' ... '5' that the user can display with the functions prev() and next(). In IE, when you go prev(), **then** next(), only the first and last records are shown. In other browsers, no problem.

```
var cache = [];
var i = 0;

function next() {
  var hist = document.getElementById('history');
  i += 1;
  if (i > 4) {
    i = 4
  };
  hist.innerHTML = '';
  hist.appendChild(cache[i]);
}

function prev() {
  var hist = document.getElementById('history');
  i -= 1;
  if (i < 0) {
    i = 0
  };
  hist.innerHTML = '';
  hist.appendChild(cache[i]);
}

function cacheInHistory(div) {
  cache.push(div.cloneNode(true));
}

function populate() {
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var hist = document.getElementById('history');
    hist.innerHTML = '';

    var Mydiv = document.createElement('div');
    Mydiv.innerHTML = i;
    hist.appendChild(Mydiv);
    cacheInHistory(Mydiv);
  }
  i = 4
}
```

Comment: You're not appending a clone, you're just appending a cached element. [Appending a clone](http://jsfiddle.net/syx91c2v/) will work in all browsers. Anyway, your original code shouldn't actually work in any browser, since `appendChild` is supposed to "cut" the element it appends, despite it being in a variable or array. Which is more weird in IE, only [the content of cached elements is cut](http://jsfiddle.net/yy4aht3u/), but the cached div elements remain.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simplify your code:

In the function populate (onload) create and populate the array cache. As last operation append your child.

In your next or previous function use replaceChild instead of append and remove innerHTML.

```js
var cache=[];
var i = 0;

function next(){
  var hist = document.getElementById('history');
  i = (++i > 4) ? 4 : i;
  hist.replaceChild(cache[i], hist.children[0]);
}
function prev(){
  var hist = document.getElementById('history');
  i = (--i < 0) ? 0 : i;
  hist.replaceChild(cache[i], hist.children[0]);
}

function cacheInHistory(div){
  cache.push(div.cloneNode(true));
}
function populate(){
  var hist = document.getElementById('history');
  for (i=0 ; i<5 ; i++){
    hist.innerHTML='';

    var Mydiv = document.createElement('div');
    Mydiv.innerHTML = i;
    cacheInHistory(Mydiv);
  }
  i = 4
  hist.appendChild(cache[i]);
}
```

```html
<body onload="populate();">
<div id="prev" onclick="prev()">
    prev
</div>
<div id="next" onclick="next()">
    next
</div>
<hr/>
<div id="history">
</div>
</body>
```